# Capybara cannot find element without js:true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Why does Capybara not find an element if I remove `js: true` (because it's very slow) from my test?

My test:

```
require 'spec_helper'
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

    feature 'signal trading platform', integration: true do
    
      scenario 'check context' do
     visit '/'
     find('a', text: 'SIGNAL TRADER').click
     end 
    end

=>
    Capybara::ElementNotFound:
        Unable to find css "a" with text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `js: true` metadata means (most likely) your test is running with the rack_test driver.  The rack_test driver doesn't process JS at all and doesn't process most CSS.  Therefore if the test worked before you removed the `js: true` metadata, either your page loading is dependent on javascript or the text was being affected by CSS which is no longer processed ( text-transform, etc).  Without seeing the actual HTML it's impossible to give a more specific answer.